# Replace default parameter binding without default route values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action in controller like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string ssn)
{
}
```

and default route values: `{controller}/{action}/{id}`

I don't want use url like `/Home/Index?ssn=1234`. I want use like `/Home/Index/1234`.
But I also don't want to add new route values for ssn parameter (or custom model binder).

Is there some complete attribute, like `[ActionName]` but for parameters?

Something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index([ParameterBinding("id")] string ssn)
{
}
```

Comment: There isn't such built-in attribute. A custom model binder or a new route entry is required for this.

Comment: I wonder, why don't you want to add a new route? If you do it correctly, it won't mess with the existing ones, if that is what you are afraid of.

Comment: 'Cause I have more than 10 actions with same signature. I don't want to add for each action custom route (ssn, email, username etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Darin & Rumi mentioned - there are no built-in attributes, however you can achieve the same affect (across multiple controllers/actions) with a single new Route using the `RouteCollection.MapRoute` constraints parameter on a single route.

The following route config will apply the "SSN" route to the Foo or Bar controller, any other controller will go through the Default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SSN",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{ssn}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { controller = "(Foo|Bar)", action = "Index" }
);
// default route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Edit: Alternatively you could use the [ActionParameterAlias](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ActionParameterAlias/) library which seems to support what you initially requested.